# The items to be shown on the Sharepoint list will depend on the user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Can you please help me on how will I able to filter the items of my list in Sharepoint depending on the user logged. The items that need to be shown will also depend to the team where the user belongs.

Thanks in advance!

So the image below shown is my list.
For example, User 1 and User 2 both have Full Control permission on my list. But User 1 should only see entries for DETE team. And User 2 should only see entries for Service Control Team.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Showing which items to be shown based on the current user can be done using out of the box SharePoint permission features.

The simplest and short answer is to set unique permissions on each item in your list to specific users or groups by breaking permission inheritance for the SharePoint list. Once the inheritance is broken, you can then specify your unique custom permissions on each item in your list. Then SharePoint will only show what is available for the user to see. If you are not familiar with security inheritance in SharePoint, then I suggest reading up on this topic as this is a foundation of SharePoint security.

To do this, use the "**Shared With**" -> "**Advanced**" options from the ellipsis menu on that item, then you can break permission inheritance on that item. (If you don't see the tool ribbon, then change the "List Experience" setting to *classic* via list settings -> advance settings -> list experience)

[image]

Then break the permission inheritance on the item:

[image]

Then you can grant permission to specific users or groups:

[image]

This can work okay for a small list but is a management nightmare for a large list.

One alternative is to use "**Folders**" and set the appropriate permissions on there instead.  Then you can add/remove items from the folder for easier management to control which users can see what. There are pros and cons with this approach but this method has worked for me. What is nice is that you can display the items with or without folders using the Folder display options when creating a custom view.

Another solution is to create a custom workflow that will apply the proper item security permissions for you when an item is created in the list. This is good to automatically set the permissions for you without doing any work but does add maintenance duties if permissions needs changing such as new users, remove users or modifying users.

Setting up the proper security groups and users should give you the flexibility needed for your security requirements.  It is always good practice to use groups when possible.

Comment: Hi. I am using SharePoint Online.

Comment: please see my additional details above. :)

Comment: I updated my response with screen shots of SharePoint Online.  I am new to the new SharePoint online layout and design but hopefully it should help you on what you need to know.

Comment: hi. is it applicable if i there will always be new items every time?

Comment: The proposed solution can work but does not mean it is the best solution for your situation. Only you can answer that question.  Have to ask yourself all sorts of questions such as how many items are being created, who are creating or maintaining these items, the level of effort needed for this.  If you feel that the out-of-the-box SharePoint security features does not meet your needs, then the only other alternatives I can see is either create a custom webpart with logic that does what you need or split the library for each team so they will not see other team's items.

Comment: Another idea that came to my mind is creating a custom workflow that will apply the specific item level permissions whenever a item is added to the list can work as well.  I updated my answer with this option.